# How do I create a series of specific days in a SQL table?

Tags: sql

I have a table called CLASSTIMES that has a column of type bool for each day of the week (SUNDAY,MONDAY,TUESDAY...etc) and also contains a STARTDATE and an ENDDATE column.  For example, I would have a row that has MONDAY and WEDNESDAY selected with a STARTDATE of June 3, 2013 and an ENDDATE of June 26, 2013.

What I'd like to be able to do is create a SPROC to insert a series of rows into a table called CLASSCALENDAR that contains all of dates between the StartDate and EndDate for each selected day column.

For example, if the user selected Monday and Wednesay from the ClassTimes table, it would generate:

```
Row    Date
1      2013-06-03
2      2013-06-10
3      2013-06-17
4      2013-06-24
5      2013-06-05
6      2013-06-12
7      2013-06-19
8      2013-06-26
```

I have tried to set this up but it is a bit over my head.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I would suggest that you start with a calendar table and then join to it for any given request.  Don't recreate it for each user/request.

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name,  I'm using MS SQL 2012.  Sorry, I'm a bit new to participating in Stack Overflow.  I didn't realize you had responded to my question so quickly.  If your example below works in MSSQL, I'll give it a try and let you know this eveing.  THANK YOU for the quick response.

Comment: Gordon,  Are you suggesting that I create a Calendar table pre-populated with dates (for example for the next 10 years), then reference that table for everything I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an SQL statement that might work for you.

```
SELECT course,
       Convert(varchar(25), course_date, 101) AS course_date
  FROM (SELECT course_no AS course,
               DATEADD(dd, rn-1, startdate) AS course_date,
               DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dd, rn-1, startdate)) AS dow
          FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c1) AS rn
                  FROM dummy) sub1,
               classtimes
         WHERE rn <= (DATEDIFF(dd, startdate, enddate)+1)
       ) list_of_dates,
       (SELECT course_no,
               (CASE monday WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday' END) AS dow
          FROM classtimes
        UNION
        SELECT course_no,
               (CASE tuesday WHEN 1 THEN 'Tuesday' END)
          FROM classtimes
        UNION
        SELECT course_no,
               (CASE wednesday WHEN 1 THEN 'Wednesday' END)          
          FROM classtimes
        UNION
        SELECT course_no,
               (CASE thursday WHEN 1 THEN 'Thursday' END)
          FROM classtimes
        UNION
        SELECT course_no,
               (CASE friday WHEN 1 THEN 'Friday' END)
          FROM classtimes
        UNION
        SELECT course_no,
               (CASE saturday WHEN 1 THEN 'Saturday' END)
          FROM classtimes
        UNION
        SELECT course_no,
               (CASE sunday WHEN 1 THEN 'Sunday' END)
          FROM classtimes
        ) class_days
 WHERE list_of_dates.dow = class_days.dow
   AND list_of_dates.course = class_days.course_no
 ORDER BY course_no,
          course_date
```

I used the query

```
SELECT course_no AS course,
       DATEADD(dd, rn-1, startdate) AS course_date,
       DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(dd, rn-1, startdate)) AS dow
  FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY c1) AS rn
          FROM dummy) sub1,
       classtimes
 WHERE rn <= (DATEDIFF(dd, startdate, enddate)+1)
```

to generate a list of all dates between the startdate and enddate for each course. In order for this query to work correctly, the **dummy** table must contain at least as many rows as the number of days between the startdate and enddate for each course.  So the result of this is a list of days between the startdate and enddate for each course, along with the day of week for that date.

```
| COURSE | COURSE_DATE |       DOW |
------------------------------------
|   MATH |  06/03/2013 |    Monday |
|   MATH |  06/04/2013 |   Tuesday |
|   MATH |  06/05/2013 | Wednesday |
|   MATH |  06/06/2013 |  Thursday |
|   MATH |  06/07/2013 |    Friday |
.........
.........
|   MATH |  06/24/2013 |    Monday |
|   MATH |  06/25/2013 |   Tuesday |
|   MATH |  06/26/2013 | Wednesday |
```

I then have a subquery that uses a series of UNIONs to take the day of week columns from the classtimes table and generate the days of the week the classes are to be held.  I then just join list_of_dates subquery with the class_days subquery to get the dates the classes are to be held.

```
|  COURSE | COURSE_DATE |
-------------------------
|    MATH |  06/03/2013 |
|    MATH |  06/05/2013 |
|    MATH |  06/10/2013 |
|    MATH |  06/12/2013 |
|    MATH |  06/17/2013 |
|    MATH |  06/19/2013 |
|    MATH |  06/24/2013 |
|    MATH |  06/26/2013 |
```

I'm sure there's a more efficient/elegant way to generate the list of the days of the week for the class from the classtimes table (the class_days subquery), but I couldn't think of one.